# Removing extensions from filename

Tags: php

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [How remove extension from string (only real extension!)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2395882/how-remove-extension-from-string-only-real-extension)
>   [Remove file extension on file upload](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7679570/remove-file-extension-on-file-upload)

I am looking for ways to remove extensions but from what i found in google are really bad examples on how to do it.

```
 $from = preg_replace('/\.[^.]+$/','',$from);
```

Something like this, any idea on how to do it?

Comment: http://php.net/pathinfo

Comment: Also http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4427397/removing-last-3-characters-on-a-file-file-extension

Answer (score 1):

Check out the [`basename`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.basename.php) function, which should do that for you. Note that it will also strip any folder names in the path.

Comment: No, it won't. basename() only presents him with the filename and extension.

Comment: I didn't understand your comment. `basename` will strip out the path and the extension and leave the base filename. That's what the OP asked for, if I understood correctly.